# How to make a module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an assignement in Android Studio about building a module which provides an image object for a given email on the website https://en.gravatar.com/. I use the libraries provided on this github https://github.com/tkeunebr/gravatar-android to help me to achieve this task.
But I never made a module, the only thing I have a mainactivity where I do everything to display an image from an input from a user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the follwing screenshot, it shows the way to create a new module, import an existing module.

[image]